# combine two excel files from columns value

Tags: php, excel

I have two excel sheets. I have to merge **per id** in Excelsheet 2 according to the mapping of excel sheet 1->Org id with excelsheet 2->Org id and first name and last name of excelsheet1 with fullname of excelsheet2.

For eg.

**Excelsheet 1**

Per id    First Name    Last Name     Org id

Per1        Marquesia       Bailey          org1

Per2        Emily                 Boyd                org2

Per3        Clint                   Hester          org3

Per4        Julie                   Coleman       org4

Per5        Steve               Fessler         org1

**Excelsheet 2**

Org id     Full Name               Per id

org1      Marquesia Bailey
org2      Emily Boyd
org4      Julie Coleman
org3      Clint Hester

**Output Excelsheet**

Org id    Full Name              Per id

org1         Marquesia Bailey     per1

org2        Emily Boyd                per2

org4        Julie Coleman           per4

org3        Clint Hester                per3

I am new to excel. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: are the Org ID's unique? That would be helpful

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate First and Full name in sheet 1 and be done with it? `=B2 &" " & C2`

Comment: hi mike kellogg.....
yes Org id is unique.. One organization (org id) has multiple person (per ids)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in Sheet2's cell `C1` and dragging down.

```
 =Index(Sheet1!A:A,Match(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!D:D,0))
```

This looks up Sheet2's orgID `A1` In sheet1's column D. Then uses that row number to return the value from sheet1'a column A to get the PerID.